# How can I omit a "Cout" statement for a specific "if-else" statement?

Tags: c++

[image]

I'm trying to avoid a `cout` statement. Specifically,

```
cout<< "Enter integer 2: \n"

cin>> i
```

I've tried utilizing the `cin.ignore(j)` in various places of the 8th if-else statement. That is, **option 8** from the user selections.

I want to accomplish this with the last complicated method. I'm in "Introduction to C++" and well, I'm not too familiar with advanced methods.

The goal here is to create a calculator with the given functions under the prototype section.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int menu();
int addition (int a, int b);
int subtract (int a, int b);
int multiply (int a, int b)
int division (int a, int b);
double realDivision (double a, double b);
double quotient (double a, double b);
double remainder (double a, double b);
int factorial (int a);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int choice, i, j;
    choice = menu();

    if (choice == 0)
        return 0;

    cout << "Enter integer 1: \n";
    cin >> i;

    cout << "Enter integer 2: \n";
    cin >> j;

    if (choice == 1)
        cout << addition(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 2)
        cout << subtract(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 3)
        cout << multiply(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 4)
        cout << division(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 5)
        cout << realDivision(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 6)
        cout << quotient(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 7)
        cout << remainder(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 8)
        cout << i << ", factorial = " << factorial(i) << endl;

        return 0;
     }

int menu()
{
  int choice = 10;
   while ((choice > 9) || (choice < 0))
   {     
     cout << "Enter 0 to quit\n";
     cout << "Enter 1 for addition\n";
     cout << "Enter 2 for subtraction\n";
     cout << "Enter 3 for Multiplication\n";
     cout << "Enter 4 for Division of two integers\n";
     cout << "Enter 5 for Real Division of two integers\n"    
     cout << "Enter 6 for Quotient of a division\n";
     cout << "Enter 7 for Remainder of a division\n";
     cout << "Enter 8 for Factorial of an integer\n";
     cout << "Enter 9 for Exponential of two integers\n";
     cin >> choice;

   }
    return choice;
}

int addition(int a, int b)
{
    return(a+b);
}

int subtract(int a, int b)
{
    return(a-b);
}

int multiply(int a, int b)
{
    return (a * b);
}

int division(int a, int b)
{
    return a/b;
}

double realDivision(double a, double b)
{
    return(a/b);
}

double quotient(double a, double b)
{
    return(a/b);
}

double remainder(double a, double b)
{
    return(a/b);
}

int factorial(int a)
{
    int product = 1;
    while (a > 1)
    {
        product *=a;
        a--;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: You mean to say that if choice is 8, you don;t want to read the 2nd number?

Comment: yes. I don't want me (the user) to be able to see that prompt at all. Only for option 8.

Comment: Check for choice before reading the 2nd number

Comment: Don't ever paste screenshots of text, paste the text itself

Answer (score 0):

You create a separate `if-else` statement which accepts second input in cases other than factorial condition. So, if a user only selects operation like **factorial/square/square root** your calculator asks for only one input from the user. You can do that simply like:

```
if (choice == 0)
        return 0;

    cout << "Enter integer 1: \n";
    cin >> i;

    if (choice == 8)
    {
        cout << i << ", factorial = 8" << factorial(i) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Enter integer 2: \n";
        cin >> j;
    }

    if (choice == 1)
        cout << addition(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 2)
        cout << subtract(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 3)
        cout << multiply(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 4)
        cout << division(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 5)
        cout << realDivision(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 6)
        cout << quotient(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 7)
        cout << remainder(i, j) << endl;

        return 0;
```

Comment: is there a more short way of doing it, within the **int factorial** function? or without having to do what you mentioned? I actually took that approach, but  it wasn't allowed.

Comment: You can only take/skip the inputs on basis of user choice at runtime with condition checking.

Comment: I wish we had GIF's to project my confusion. But ok...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the factorial choice is always 8.You can check for `choice!=8` before reading the second number.If the choice is 8, it will skip the 2nd number part and then continue else it will read the 2nd number and then continue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int menu();
int addition (int a, int b);
int subtract (int a, int b);
int multiply (int a, int b)
int division (int a, int b);
double realDivision (double a, double b);
double quotient (double a, double b);
double remainder (double a, double b);
int factorial (int a);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int choice, i, j;
    choice = menu();

    if (choice == 0)
        return 0;

    cout << "Enter integer 1: \n";
    cin >> i;

    if(choice!=8)
    cout << "Enter integer 2: \n";
    cin >> j;

    if (choice == 1)
        cout << addition(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 2)
        cout << subtract(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 3)
        cout << multiply(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 4)
        cout << division(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 5)
        cout << realDivision(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 6)
        cout << quotient(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 7)
        cout << remainder(i, j) << endl;

    else if (choice == 8)
        cout << i << ", factorial = 8" << factorial(i) << endl;

        return 0;
     }

int menu()
{
  int choice = 10;
   while ((choice > 9) || (choice < 0))
   {     
     cout << "Enter 0 to quit\n";
     cout << "Enter 1 for addition\n";
     cout << "Enter 2 for subtraction\n";
     cout << "Enter 3 for Multiplication\n";
     cout << "Enter 4 for Division of two integers\n";
     cout << "Enter 5 for Real Division of two integers\n"    
     cout << "Enter 6 for Quotient of a division\n";
     cout << "Enter 7 for Remainder of a division\n";
     cout << "Enter 8 for Factorial of an integer\n";
     cout << "Enter 9 for Exponential of two integers\n";
     cin >> choice;

   }
    return choice;
}

int addition(int a, int b)
{
    return(a+b);
}

int subtract(int a, int b)
{
    return(a-b);
}

int multiply(int a, int b)
{
    return (a * b);
}

int division(int a, int b)
{
    return a/b;
}

double realDivision(double a, double b)
{
    return(a/b);
}

double quotient(double a, double b)
{
    return(a/b);
}

double remainder(double a, double b)
{
    return(a/b);
}

int factorial(int a)
{
    int product = 1;
    while (a > 1)
    {
        product *=a;
        a--;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question: it's not suppose to say **factorial = 8** , but rather **factorial =** . However, I'm still confused as to how I can check for the second input? I mean, the whole point is not regarding the second input, but more so, dismissing the question all together. Can you explain?

Comment: @RudyV I have updated my answer. I hope it will help.

Comment: Yasss! Thank you Jibin!

Comment: can you briefly explain the logic behind the while loop in the main function? That is, why isn't it, While choice is < 10 or >0? The way it's formatted seems to be outside the parameters of the answers.